# How can search results be live and updated using Javascript accessing a Python application?

Tags: jquery, python, sqlalchemy, flask

I currently have a simple python application built on Flask and SQLAlchemy. The application is accesses a database `User` imported from another python file. The application has two views, one is `home`

```
def home()
    if request.method == 'POST':
            search = Search(query=request.form['searchbox'], time=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
            db.session.add(search)
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('results', query=request.form['searchbox']))
    return render_template('mainin.html')
```

which simply displays the index page and passes the data in the `searchbox` to the second view, `results` where they are displayed.

```
def results(query):
    results = User.query.filter(User.username.contains(query)).all()
    return render_template('results.html', results=results)
```

However, I instead want the results to be displayed on the same page as the searchbox, under where the user types their query. I think the effect I am going for is live results like when searching StackOverflow. I have done many searches, and I now realize that to achieve this effect I should just JQuery in the `mainin.html` page to make calls to the database as characters are entered into the search box. Currently, results are fetched by POST when the form's button is hit. So I assume that the JQuery needs to make a similar POST automatically, though I am not sure where to start. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: look at [jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl – the source there makes complete sense. However there, they have a variable with all of the types of tags. Instead of listing all of the search result possibilites as a variable, can it search my database?

Comment: Of course it can search your database. specify a file as the source parameter, such as, `source: 'myfile.py'`; The request type will always be post, the dataType will be sent as JSON, and you will access `term` within the post array to get the valid being sent. Make sure you send back a value JSON string in `label: var, value: var` pairs and you're good to go.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy can actually send back a simple array of values also but not sure why anyone wouldn't take the little extra time to set up key/values

Comment: @zch look at more of the demos like the custom data...can include and access all sorts of data in return